# Call to undefined method App\Models\Karyawan::links() - Pagination in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, pagination

I have this code in my controller:

```
public function data_karyawan()
    {
        return view('data-karyawan', [
            "title" => "Data Karyawan",
            "karyawan" => Karyawan::with(['role', 'user'])->search(request(['search']))->paginate(10)
        ]);
    }
```

but when I tried to give pagination on my view like this, there is an error:

```
{{ $karyawan->links() }}
```

what did I do wrong?

Blade file:

```
@extends('layouts.main')

@section('container')    
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
   
    <nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar collapse">
        <div class="position-sticky pt-3">
          <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-3 bg-light" style="width: 200px;">
              <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="0"></svg>
              <span class="fs-10"><center><img src="/images/logo/selindo4.png" style="width:100px"></center></span>
            </a>
            <hr>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="/admin" class="nav-link link-dark">
                  <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="40"><use xlink:href="#home"/></svg>
                  Home
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">
                  <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="40"><use xlink:href="#people-circle"/></svg>
                  Data Karyawan
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/admin/data-departemen" class="nav-link link-dark">
                  <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="40"><use xlink:href="#speedometer2"/></svg>
                  Departemen
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/admin/data-cuti" class="nav-link link-dark">
                  <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="40"><use xlink:href="#table"/></svg>
                  Summary Cuti
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <hr>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center link-dark text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser2" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <img src="/images/avatar/avatar-2.png" alt="" width="32" height="40" class="rounded-circle me-2">
                <strong>Admin</strong>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser2">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>

    <main class="col-md-9 ms-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
          <h1 class="h2" style="position:absolute margin: auto auto"><p></p>Data Karyawan</h1>
        </div>
      
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <form action="/admin/data-karyawan">
              <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cari Karyawan" name = "search" value="{{ request('search') }}">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>

        <center>
          <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
            <hr>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>No.</th>
                  <th>NIK</th>
                  <th>Nama</th>
                  <th>JK</th>
                  <th>Tempat Lahir</th>
                  <th>Tanggal Lahir</th>
                  <th>Alamat</th>
                  <th>Agama</th>
                  <th>Jabatan</th>
                  <th>Divisi</th>
                  <th>Role</th>
                  <th>E-mail</th>
                  <th>Action</th>  
                </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
                <?php
                  $i = 1;
                  foreach ($karyawan as $karyawan) { ?>
              <tr>
                <td>{{ $i++ }}</td>
                <td>{{ $karyawan["nik"] }}</td> 
                <td>{{ $karyawan["nama"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $karyawan["jk"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $karyawan["tempat_lahir"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $karyawan["tanggal_lahir"] }}</td> 
                <td>{{ $karyawan["alamat"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $karyawan["agama"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $karyawan["jabatan"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $karyawan["departemen"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $karyawan->role->nama_role }}</td>
                <td>{{ $karyawan->user->email }}</td>
                <td width = '180px'>
                  <a href="update.php?nik=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($karyawan['nik']); ?>" class="btn btn-warning" role="button">Update</a>
                  <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>?nik=<?php echo $karyawan['nik']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Delete</a>
                  </td>
              </tr>
              <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </center>
        <table>
          <tr>  <td><a href="/admin/create" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Tambah Data Karyawan</a></td>
              <td width='100px'>&nbsp;</td><td width='100px'>&nbsp;</td><td width='100px'>&nbsp;</td>
              <td width='100px'>&nbsp;</td><td width='100px'>&nbsp;</td><td width='100px'>&nbsp;</td>
              <td width='100px'>&nbsp;</td><td width='100px'>&nbsp;</td><td width='25px'>&nbsp;</td>
            </table>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>

{{ $karyawan->links() }}

@endsection
```

thank you very much.

Comment: Can you show full view?

Comment: Hello, @geertjanknapen here is my full view:

[link] https://codeshare.io/loqyNj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an issue here :

```
$karyawan as $karyawan
```

you override the value

Answer (score 0):

In your blade file, you use the same variables for your foreach statement. Thefore overriding one.

Change `foreach ($karyawan as $karyawan)` to something like `foreach ($karyawan as $kar)` and then replace all occurances of `$karyawan` in the below block with `$kar`

```
<td>{{ $karyawan["nik"] }}</td> 
                <td>{{ $karyawan["nama"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $karyawan["jk"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $karyawan["tempat_lahir"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $karyawan["tanggal_lahir"] }}</td> 
                <td>{{ $karyawan["alamat"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $karyawan["agama"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $karyawan["jabatan"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $karyawan["departemen"] }}</td>
                <td>{{ $karyawan->role->nama_role }}</td>
                <td>{{ $karyawan->user->email }}</td>
                <td width = '180px'>
                  <a href="update.php?nik=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($karyawan['nik']); ?>" class="btn btn-warning" role="button">Update</a>
                  <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>?nik=<?php echo $karyawan['nik']; ?>" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Delete</a>
                  </td>
```